# Return all possible permutations and combinations of numbers from n arrays whose sum is less than m and greater than r

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I have two arrays:

```
array1: [0 1 2 3]
array2: [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
array3: [0 1 2 3 4 5]
```

I want to find combination from each array like 1 element from each array such that the `sum >= m` eg.3 and `sum <=r` eg. 6

```
Example:
array1  array2  array3 elements
1          1    1       (sum is 3)
1          5    0       (sum is 6)

1          6     1       (wrong result sum is greater than 6)
```

Thanks in advance.

I don't understand how to solve this problem . A pseudocode will be very helpful.

Comment: Start off with a simple brute-force approach. Generate all combinations and filter the ones not matching the constraints out.

Comment: Like @Paul menioned, you can start off by checking the sum for each element in `array1` with each element in `array2` and so on..

Comment: Thanks, but is there any more faster result generating algorithm?

Comment: @Jagrati sure. You can filter quite a few combinations out, before completing the sum. But if you want to generate all possible combinations there won't be any way around generating all possible combinations...

Comment: Linearly select the first and second elements from 2 arrays (arrays A & B) and use binary search to find third element in (array C) . Of course better to sort all the arrays initially.

Comment: @sameerkn what if I have 4 arrays.

Comment: apply brute force for taking elements and check whether their sum is upto m or not. if m is less then their sum then break the last loop here.

Comment: `0` is neutral for your condition so you can safely deduct zeroes from each array as a starter and then you may deduct those items larger than your top limit (6 in this particular case) as well. Then concatenate all arrays into one to obtain it's sub arrays those fit in your condition. A dynamical programming approach would make it very fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have mentioned in my comment; compared to the brute force, in JS by a dynamical programming approach you may get the results much faster, like in total around 10ms for your test case, as follows;

```js
function getCombos(arr,n,m){

  function getBinaryMap(d){
    return Array(a.length).fill()
                          .reduce((p,c,i) => p.concat(d >> i & 1),[]);
  }

  var a = arr.reduce((p,c) => p.concat(c.filter(e => e !== 0 && e <= m)),[]);
      t = [0],
      r = [];
  a.forEach(e => t = t.concat(t.map((f,i) => (f + e >= n && f + e <= m && r.push(getBinaryMap(t.length + i)), f + e))));
  return r.map(e => e.reduce((p,c,i) => c ? p.concat(a[i]) : p,[]));;
}

var arrays = [[0, 1, 2, 3],[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]];
    result = getCombos(arrays,3,6);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

Let there be N=3 sorted arrays A(size = p),  B(size = q) and C(size=r).

Choose a number say X and try finding a sum of N=3 numbers x1 + x2 + x3
such that X = x1 + x2 + x3. Finding x1, x2 and x3 can be done using dynamic programming.

Now,

Consider the sequence ABC and use binary search to find x1 in array A, x2 in array B and x3 in array C.

Consider the sequence ACB and use binary search to find x1 in array A, x2 in array C and x3 in array B.

Consider the sequence BAC and use binary search to find x1 in array B, x2 in array A and x3 in array C.

You will find that there are N! number of such sequences.

You will be required to repeat the above process for all X such that [m]<=[X]<=[r].

Total Complexity would be (r - m + 1) * (N!) * ((log p) + (log q) + (log r)).

Total Complexity does not include the dynamic programming part.